# How to Display row even if a record does not exist in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I Have a table called books

```
books
 - bookid
 - userid(fk)
 - bookname
```

And I Have a table named paid

```
paid
 - paidid(pk)
 - userid(fk)
 - link
 - bookid(fk)
```

My query :

```
SELECT * 
FROM books,paid
WHERE books.bookid = paid.bookidfk
AND books.useridfk = '$userid'";
```

That only shows records that have been paid for but I still want to display all books from the user even if its not paid for.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for an `outer join`:

```
select *
from books b
   left join paid p on b.bookid = p.bookidfk
where b.useridfk = '$userid';
```

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a LEFT JOIN to return all books for the user along with paid data when available.  ANSI 92 syntax:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    books
        LEFT JOIN paid ON books.bookid = paid.bookidfk
WHERE   books.useridfk = '$userid';
```

I suggest you avoid using the `*` shorthand in production code and instead specify the desired list of columns.

Comment: Why post the same answer as already posted?  Instead, upvote the answer you agree with...

Comment: @user2480596, the question had not been answered as I composed mine, or I would have simply upvoted with a comment about the `*`.\